# Pygame draw interactively

Tags: python, pygame, mouse, draw, interactive

Hi I'm having some trouble realizing my ideas. I first wanted to draw rectangles with two mouse clicks, but it didn't work properly so i reduced it to this: to draw fixed-size rectangles with one mouse click.
However it still doesn't work/...

```
import pygame
windowSize = (500,500)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(windowSize)
running = 1

while running:
    screen.fill(white)
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = 0
```

THE PROBLEM IS HERE SOMEWHERRE

```
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            rect = pygame.Rect(event.dict["pos"],(30,50))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,rect,1)


    pygame.display.flip()
```

I know there might be a lot of conceptual errors with my code... please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filling white the entire screen every tick. So after you actually draw the screen become blank again on the next tick. Just move `screen.fill(white)` out of main cycle:

```
import pygame
windowSize = (500,500)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(windowSize)
running = 1

screen.fill(white)
while running:
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            rect = pygame.Rect(event.dict["pos"],(30,50))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,rect,1)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: thanks! and what if i need to update the same rectangle over and over again?

Comment: @kwan Depends on what you mean. If it's same primitive, you may store all coords for rectangles in some array and then clear screen every tick (like you did before) and redraw all rectangles from this array. If you mean updating rectangle area at the screen you may use `pygame.display.update(rects)` where `rects` is a list of `pygame.Rect` objects.